# Does MPI have its own way of transferring files to remote nodes?

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I have a cluster of machines that are configured to talk to each other via ssh. I would like to run an MPI job on this cluster. It seems like any executable I wish to run must be present in every node of the cluster. I could manually transfer the executable from the master node to all the others, but is there a more natural way to do this from within MPI?

For instance, if I run `mpirun --hostfile hosts a.out` it requires me to manually copy `a.out` into the home directories of every single node. Doesn't MPI have its own way to automate this?

Comment: MPI does not do it for you. The “natural way” is to put your binaries and data on a shared filesystem (such as Lustre or even NFS).

Comment: Think that `mpirun` does an `ssh` command to each host to run the executable. That presumes it's already present there.